# Using a version of the strong Markov Property of Brownian motion to prove the reflection principle

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stopping-times

The following is from Rene Schilling's Brownian motion. Let $B_t$ be a one-dimensional Brownian motion and $\tau_b$ the first time it hits $b$. Then we have

$$P(\tau_b \le t, B_t < b) = E(1_{\tau_b \le t} E[1_{(-\infty,0)}(B_t-b)|\mathscr{F}_{\tau_b}^B])=E(1_{\tau_b\le t} E^{B_{\tau_b}} [1_{(-\infty,0)}(B_{t-\tau_b} -b)])= E(1_{\tau_b \le t} E[1_{(0,\infty)} (B_{t-\tau_b})).$$

Note that as it is written, we do not know whether $t-\tau_b$ is positive.In order to make such arguments work we use the following stronger version of the strong Markov property.

> **Theorem 6.11.** Let $B_t$ be a $BM^d$, $\tau$ an $\mathscr{F}_t^B$ stopping time and $\eta\ge \tau$ where $\eta$ is an $\mathscr{F}_{\tau+}^B$ measurable random time. Then we have for all $\omega \in \{\eta < \infty\}$ and all $u \in \mathscr{B}_b(\mathbb{R}^d)$
> $$E[u(B_\eta)|\mathscr{F}_{\tau+}^B](\omega)=E^{B_\tau(\omega)}[u(B_{\eta(\omega)-\tau(\omega)}(\cdot))].$$

In the end, we want to show that $P(\tau_b \le t, B_t < b) = P(\tau_b \le t, B_t > b)$. So we need $E(1_{\tau_b \le t} E[1_{(0,\infty)}(B_{t-\tau_b})]) =P(\tau_b\le t, B_t>b)$. But how does this hold?

Answer (score 0):

A simple consequence of the strong markov property is that
$B_t'=B_{\tau+t}-b$ is a Brownian motion which is independent of $\mathscr{F}^B_{\tau}$.

Once we have this, we can deduce the reflection principle by noting that $B_t''=-B_{\tau+t}+b$ is also a Brownian motion independent of $\mathscr{F}^B_{\tau}$. So $B^1=1_{t<\tau}B_t+1_{t>\tau}B_t'$ and $B^2=1_{t<\tau}B_t+1_{t>\tau}B_t''$ are both Brownian motions. By expanding the definitions, $B^1_t=B_t$ and $B^2_t=1_{t<\tau}B_t+(2b-B_t)1_{t>\tau}$, and the principle follows easily.